# Massive read Problem with LSI SAS 9211-8i Host Bus Adapter under 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, raid

I have a new installed 14.04.3 system with massive read problems from a raid 10 over a Avago LSI SAS 9211-8i Host Bus Adapter. 
I tried to install the latest driver

- downloaded "Linux Driver-RH5_SLES10_P20"
- unpacked "mpt2sas-20.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu14.04.amd64.deb" out of it
- sudo dpkg -i mpt2sas-20.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu14.04.amd64.deb

After that there is still only the old driver 18.100... there (modinfo mpt2sas):

filename: /lib/modules/3.19.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt2sas/mpt2sas.ko

version:18.100.00.00

license:GPL

description:LSI MPT Fusion SAS 2.0 Device Driver
author:LSI Corporation

srcversion:9C2D2E9D612CABAE32B581D

Question - how to get the new version installed?

Comment: Problem solved - it was the e x t r e m l y buggy P20 Bios/Firmware of the Card - I flashed to P19 (P18 or P15 are also "working" ones) and it worked perfect! 

Btw - the f*cked up P20 Version is more than a year old and still the newest "standard" which comes together when you buy a new card - in the future i think i´ll stop buying Avago/LSI products! :(